# Normalize samples with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg

I am writing application for music analysis. I wrote resampling module relying on ffmpeg. Currently, I have AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 but later I have converting to float, which can be time consuming.

Because I need samples to be in some reasonable interval I need to do some kind of normalization, for AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT samples.

So, how I can normalize samples which I get when I select AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT. Ideal interval would be -n to n, where n is greater than equal of 1.f

Answer (score 0):

Given that AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT is already normalised to the -1 .. 1 range, we can multiply each sample by your 'n' value to have it scaled between -n .. n

Comment: Samples I get aren't in [-1,1]. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/87afd9892131f876e4096cefb32ff40d.

I am using resampler to resample everything I get to 44KHz Mono for processing. Globals::DestinationSampleRate = 44100;

Comment: According to documentation AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT should be normalized in that range, unless I misread. Without knowing the upper and lower bound you cannot normalize.

Comment: I read somewhere similar information, either I missed something or this doesn't return normalized data...